# Vectorizing 4 nested for loops

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the 2 inner nested `for` loops, but I can't come up with a way to do this. The `FS1` and `FS2` functions have been written to accept argument for `N_theta` and `N_e`, which is what the loops are iterating over

```
%% generate regions
for raw_r=1:visual_field_width
    for raw_c=1:visual_field_width       
        r = raw_r - center_r;
        c = raw_c - center_c;

        % convert (r,c) to polar: (eccentricity, angle)
        e = sqrt(r^2+c^2)*deg_per_pixel;
        a = mod(atan2(r,c),2*pi);

        for nt=1:N_theta
            for ne=1:N_e
                regions(raw_r, raw_c, nt, ne) = ...
                    FS_1(nt-1,a,N_theta) * ...
                    FS_2(ne-1,e,N_e,e0_in_deg, e_max);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Ideally, I could replace the two inner nested for loops by:

```
regions(raw_r,raw_c,:,:) = FS_1(:,a,N_theta) * FS_2(:,N_e,e0_in_deg,e_max);
```

But this isn't possible. Maybe I'm missing an easy fix or vectorization technique? `e0_in_deg` and `e_max` are parameters.

The `FS_1` function is

```
function h = FS_1(n,theta,N,t)

if nargin==2
    N = 9;
    t=1/2;
elseif nargin==3
    t=1/2;
end

w = (2*pi)/N;

theta = theta + w/4;

if n==0 && theta>(3/2)*pi
    theta = theta - 2*pi;
end
h = FS_f((theta - (w*n + 0.5*w*(1-t)))/w);
```

the `FS_2` function is

```
function g = FS_gne(n,e,N,e0, e_max)

if nargin==2
    N = 10;
    e0 = .5;
elseif nargin==3
    e0 = .5;
end


w = (log(e_max) - log(e0))/N;
g = FS_f((log(e)-log(e0)-w*(n+1))/w);
```

and the `FS_f` function is

```
function f = FS_f(x, t)

if nargin<2
    t = 0.5;
end

f = zeros(size(x));

% case 1
idx = x>-(1+t)/2 & x<=(t-1)/2;
f(idx) = (cos(0.5*pi*((x(idx)-(t-1)/2)/t))).^2;

% case 2
idx = x>(t-1)/2 & x<=(1-t)/2;
f(idx) = 1;

% case 3
idx = x>(1-t)/2 & x<=(1+t)/2;
f(idx) = -(cos(0.5*pi*((x(idx)-(1+t)/2)/t))).^2+1;
```

Comment: Are `FS_1`, `FS_2` functions or variables?

Comment: Could the inner workings of those functions be shared?

Comment: Ok, please see edits.

Comment: What do `case 1`, `case 2` & `case 3` mean in function `FS_f`?

Comment: They have to do with different setting to get the FS_f function, depending on how it varies.

Answer (score 0):

I had to assume values for the constants, and then used `ndgrid` to find the possible configurations and `sub2ind` to get the indices. Doing this I removed all loops. Let me know if this produced the correct values.

```
function RunningFunction
    %% generate regions

    visual_field_width = 10;
    center_r = 2;
    center_c = 3;

    deg_per_pixel = 17;
    N_theta = 2;
    N_e = 5;
    e0_in_deg = 35;
    e_max = 17;

    [raw_r, raw_c, nt, ne] = ndgrid(1:visual_field_width, 1:visual_field_width, 1:N_theta, 1:N_e);
    ind = sub2ind(size(raw_r), raw_r, raw_c, nt, ne);

    r = raw_r - center_r;
    c = raw_c - center_c;

    % convert (r,c) to polar: (eccentricity, angle)
    e = sqrt(r.^2+c.^2)*deg_per_pixel;
    a = mod(atan2(r,c),2*pi);

    regions(ind) = ...
        FS_1(nt-1,a,N_theta) .* ...
        FS_2(ne-1,e,N_e,e0_in_deg, e_max);

    regions = reshape(regions, size(raw_r));

end

function h = FS_1(n,theta,N,t)
    if nargin==2
        N = 9;
        t=1/2;
    elseif nargin==3
        t=1/2;
    end

    w = (2*pi)./N;

    theta = theta + w/4;

    theta(n==0 & theta>(3/2)*pi) = theta(n==0 & theta>(3/2)*pi) - 2*pi;

    h = FS_f((theta - (w*n + 0.5*w*(1-t)))/w);
end

function g = FS_2(n,e,N,e0, e_max)

if nargin==2
    N = 10;
    e0 = .5;
elseif nargin==3
    e0 = .5;
end


w = (log(e_max) - log(e0))/N;
g = FS_f((log(e)-log(e0)-w*(n+1))/w);
end

function f = FS_f(x, t)
    if nargin<2
        t = 0.5;
    end

    f = zeros(size(x));

    % case 1
    idx = x>-(1+t)/2 & x<=(t-1)/2;
    f(idx) = (cos(0.5*pi*((x(idx)-(t-1)/2)/t))).^2;

    % case 2
    idx = x>(t-1)/2 & x<=(1-t)/2;
    f(idx) = 1;

    % case 3
    idx = x>(1-t)/2 & x<=(1+t)/2;
    f(idx) = -(cos(0.5*pi*((x(idx)-(1+t)/2)/t))).^2+1;
end
```

Comment: Hi, I actually ran it but the computer ended up running out of memory (for the parameters I established in the question). On the flipside, I managed to get it working using a similar method you did, and by creating a grid with all values that have been pre-computed